# Java concatenation of primitive type to String

Tags: java, primitive, autoboxing

Is the reason you can concatenate a primitive type to a String due to autoboxing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

The java language handles concatenation of primitives with Strings natively.

It was part of the language's first release - pre-dating autoboxing by about 10 years